# Why does this scanner not eat whitespaces?

Tags: regex, whitespace, bison, flex-lexer

These are my lexer-definitions, there are many lexer-definitions but this one is mine. I have several regexes trying to capture and ignore whitespace, from this sample. The error I get is that in line 1: 14 there is a `$undefined Symbold` to be found - that is of asci-value 32.

Also known as space.

```
OIL_VERSION = "314159OS";


CPU AT91SAM7S256
{
    //Test Coment

    OS HTOSEK
    {
        STATUS = EXTENDED;
        STARTUPHOOK = TRUE;
        ERRORHOOK = FALSE;
        SHUTDOWNHOOK = FALSE;
        PRETASKHOOK = FALSE;
        POSTTASKHOOK = FALSE;
        USEGETSERVICEID = FALSE;
        USEPARAMETERACCESS = FALSE;
        USERESSCHEDULER = FALSE;
        USR_STACK_SIZE=3000;
    };

    /* Definition of application mode */
    APPMODE appmode1{}; 

    /* Definition of resource */
    RESOURCE resource1
    {
        RESOURCEPROPERTY = STANDARD;
    };

    /* Definition of event */
    EVENT event1
    {
        MASK = AUTO;
    };
...
```

Lex Capture Definitions:

```
%{ /*** C/C++ Declarations ***/
#define MAX_INCLUDE_DEPTH 16
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define SSTR( x ) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
        ( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()
#include "scanner.h"

/* import the parser's token type into a local typedef */
typedef implementation::Parser::token token;
typedef implementation::Parser::token_type token_type;

/* By default yylex returns int, we use token_type. Unfortunately yyterminate
 * by default returns 0, which is not of token_type. */
#define yyterminate() return token::END

/* This disables inclusion of unistd.h, which is not available under Visual C++
 * on Win32. The C++ scanner uses STL streams instead. */
#define YY_NO_UNISTD_H

static int once = 0;

static int lineno = 1;

 static void nextLine()
   {
     lineno++;
   }


 //convert a str to int
  int fromInt(char *s)
    {
      int i;
      int m;
      m = 1;
      i = 0;

      if (s[0]=='-'){
    m = -1;
    i = 1;
      }
      else if(s[0]=='+')
    i = 1;
      return((atoi(s+i))*m);
    }

  int fromHex(char *s)
    {
      return((int)strtol(s, NULL, 16));
    }


int LineCounter=0;

%}

/*** Flex Declarations and Options ***/

/* enable c++ scanner class generation */
%option c++

/* change the name of the scanner class. results in "ExampleFlexLexer" */
%option prefix="Example"

/* the manual says "somewhat more optimized" */
%option batch

/* enable scanner to generate debug output. disable this for release
 * versions. */
%option debug

/* no support for include files is planned */
%option yywrap nounput 

/* enables the use of start condition stacks */
%option stack

%x C_COMMENT
%x incl


/* The following paragraph suffices to track locations accurately. Each time
 * yylex is invoked, the begin position is moved onto the end position. */
%{
#define YY_USER_ACTION  yylloc->columns(yyleng);
%}

%% /*** Regular Expressions Part ***/

 /* code to place at the beginning of yylex() */
%{
    // reset location
    yylloc->step();
%}




"/*"                                                    { BEGIN(C_COMMENT); }
<C_COMMENT>"*/"                                         { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<C_COMMENT>.                                            { }
"="                                                     { return(token::EQ);
                                                        }
"["                                                     { return(token::LBRACK);
                                                        }
"]"                                                     { return(token::RBRACK);
                                                        }
"OS"                                                    { return(token::OSEK);
                                                        }
"EVENT"                                                 { return(token::EVENT);
                                                        }
"TASK"                                                  { return(token::TASK);
                                                        }
"ALARM"                                                 { return(token::ALARM);
                                                        }
"COUNTER"                                               { return(token::COUNTER);
                                                        }
"OIL_VERSION"                                           { return(token::OIL_VERSION);
                                                        }
"APPMODE"                                               { return(token::APPMODE);
                                                        }
"CPU"                                                   { return (token::CPU);
                                                        }
"true"|"TRUE"                                           { yylval->integerVal =1; return(token::VAL_BOOL);
                                                        }
"false"|"FALSE"                                         { yylval->integerVal =0; return(token::VAL_BOOL);
                                                        }
"BOOLEAN"                                               { return(token::BOOLEAN);
                                                        }
"INT"                                                   { return(token::INT);
                                                        }
"{"                                                     { return(token::LBRACE);
                                                        }
"}"                                                     { return(token::RBRACE);
                                                        }
":"                                                     { return(token::COLON);
                                                        }
","                                                     { return(token::COMMA);
                                                        }
";"                                                     { return(token::SEMI);
                                                        }
([_A-Za-z])([a-zA-Z0-9!^_])*                            {yylval->stringVal =  new std::string(yytext, yyleng);
                                                        return(token::STRING);
                                                        }

(([+-])?([0-9])*)                                       {yylval->integerVal = fromInt( yytext );
                                                        return(token::NUMERAL);
                                                        }
(("0x")([0-9ABCDEFabcdef])*)                            {yylval->integerVal =  fromHex( yytext );
                                                        return(token::NUMERAL);
                                                        }
(([-+]?[1-9][0-9]+\.[0-9]*)|([-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)|([-+]?[1-9]+))([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?(f)?  { yylval->doubleVal=atof(yytext);
                                                                                        return (token::VAL_FLOAT);
                                                                                        }
[\n\r]+                                                 {
                                                        //yylloc->lines(yyleng);
                                                        yylloc->step();
                                                        LineCounter++;
                                                        //return token::EOL;

                                                        }       
[\r\n]+                                                 {
                                                        //yylloc->lines(yyleng);
                                                        yylloc->step();LineCounter++;
                                                        //return token::EOL;
                                                        }

[\t\r]+                                                 { /* gobble up white-spaces */  yylloc->step(); }
[\s]+                                                   {  yylloc->step(); }



\"([^\"])*\"                                            {
                                                        yytext[yyleng-1]= 0;

                                                        yylval->stringVal = new std::string( yytext, yyleng);
                                                        return(token::STRING);
                                                        }


.                                                       {
                                                        unsigned int temp;
                                                        temp= (unsigned int)(*yytext);
                                                        std::stringstream str2;
                                                        str2<<temp;
                                                        std::cout<<"Unknown character"<<*yytext<<" as Asci-value : "<<str2.str()<<std::endl; 
                                                        return static_cast<token_type>(*yytext);    
                                                        }                                                       

%% /*** Additional Code ***/

namespace implementation {

Scanner::Scanner(std::istream* in,
         std::ostream* out)
    : ExampleFlexLexer(in, out)
{
}

Scanner::~Scanner()
{
}

void Scanner::set_debug(bool b)
{
    yy_flex_debug = b;
}

}

/* This implementation of ExampleFlexLexer::yylex() is required to fill the
 * vtable of the class ExampleFlexLexer. We define the scanner's main yylex
 * function via YY_DECL to reside in the Scanner class instead. */

#ifdef yylex
#undef yylex
#endif

int ExampleFlexLexer::yylex()
{
    std::cerr << "in ExampleFlexLexer::yylex() !" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/* When the scanner receives an end-of-file indication from YY_INPUT, it then
 * checks the yywrap() function. If yywrap() returns false (zero), then it is
 * assumed that the function has gone ahead and set up `yyin' to point to
 * another input file, and scanning continues. If it returns true (non-zero),
 * then the scanner terminates, returning 0 to its caller. */

int ExampleFlexLexer::yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I modified the last rule, so it simply doesent try to cast any unknown text and print out the ascisymbols it captures.. resulting in 32 47 47 32 " // ".
Will try to print out the stream..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flex does not implement perlisms such as `\s`. The only backslash escape sequences it recognized are standard C escapes such as `\n`. If you want to recognise a space character, use `" "`.

By the way, `[\n\r]+` and `[\r\n]+` recognize exactly the same thing: one or more repetitions of a single character which is either a newline or a return. So the second such rule will never match. I think flex will warn you about that.

Comment: Did that and it worked. Im still having trouble, but that is another question, and shall be asked another time. Unfortunatly stackoverflow has to split it all up into atomic questions, and doesent allow questions to be lined up into procedures. Thanks.